# PHP Get year of last week given one day of next year

Tags: php, datetime

I have these dates as follows:

```
2016-12-30
2016-12-31
2017-01-01
```

With the following PHP code:

```
$my_date = new DateTime();
$my_week = $my_date ->format("W");
$my_year = $my_date ->format("Y");
```

I get this result:

```
2016-12-30 -> week 52 / year 2016
2016-12-31 -> week 52 / year 2016
2017-01-01 -> week 52 / year 2017
```

I need to get the year of last week that corresponds to days of 2017.

In my example I need this:

```
2017-01-01 -> week 52 / year 2016
```

(because correspond to week 52 of 2016 according to ISO-8601)

How I get this data with PHP ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date

Comment: Perhaps take a look at the Carbon library, which is an PHP date time library for manipulating/calculating time. This migth be usefull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get year and week use the following code:

```
<?php
   $d = new DateTime("2017-01-01");
   $res =  $d->format('o-\WW-N');

   $r = explode('-',$res);

   echo "week ".$r[1]." / year ".$r[0];
?>
```

https://eval.in/709321

Comment: But I need to get year not week

Comment: Yes! perfect and clean